# How would you go about creating a favorites tab for an iphone application?

Tags: iphone, core-data, favorites

I would like to add a favorites tab to my iphone app that i am developing. I am using core data to populate a UITableView and would like in the detailed view to be able to add the selected item to the users favorites.

Would i go about this by adding the selected item to a new array?

I am very new to xcode and iphone programming so as much help and code would be gratefully received.

Answer (score -1):

hey ive been trying to solve this problem however for my app the data is in an array. you could use the writeToFile:atomically: to save the file
and the arrayWithContentsOfFile class to load the file
i hope this helps...